# Asp.Net Core TempData attribute - value is always null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, tempdata

I'm using the `[TempData]` attribute on a property of my Controller class, e.g:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [TempData]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
  
    ....
}
```

And setting this value in an Index action handling a GET request:

```
public IActionResult Index(string returnUrl = null)
{
    this.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

    // Do stuff...

    return View();
}
```

I have a second action handling a POST request which is raised from the first (Index) action, it's here that I need to read the `TempData` value back:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult HandlePost(int id)
{
    // Do post things...

    // Read value from [TempData] backed property
    string returnUrl = this.ReturnUrl;
    
    return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

However I'm finding that the value of the `ReturnUrl` property is always `null`.

But if I use `TempData` directly like this:

```
// Set return url
TempData["returnUrl"] = returnUrl;
```

And

```
// Get return url
string returnUrl = TempData["returnUrl"] as string;
```

It works fine - am I using the attribute incorrectly? Is it possible to use `[TempData]` in this way?

Comment: Controller property with `[TempData]` attribute will have value assigned only once by temp data provider, because in order to assign the property value, the provider removes the entry from temp data dictionary while accessing it. That's how the temp data works. Ensure that no requests are made to your controller in between the GET and POST requests. Any request to your controller will trigger filling the temp property, thus removing the entry. If you want more control, consider using [memory cache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: @Prolog - yes i think this is the problem. There aren't any requests to the controller between the GET/POST however stepping through the code I can see that the property getter is accessed just after the GET request, which is strange, because the only place that the property is being read is within the POST... any idea why/how the getter would be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

I can get returnUrl with `this.ReturnUrl`,here is a demo:

Controller:

```
public class Test1Controller : Controller
    {
        [TempData]
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
        public IActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            this.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult HandlePost()
        {
            string returnUrl = this.ReturnUrl;
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="HandlePost">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

url:

```
https://localhost:44355/Test1?returnUrl=ssss
```

result:
[image]